# Change default color in ggplot geo_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud733.jpg)I want to change the default fill color of my `geom_bars` but am getting an error message. I had set the fill function to my variable ( Accident_severity_combined) in order to show the distribution of the severity within the bars but would like to change the default colours that come up.. but am getting the error msg as follows : non-numeric argument to binary operator

When omitting the function `scale_fill_manual`, the chart loads up fine. ?

```
 p<- ggplot(uk, aes(x = Road_Type)) + 
 geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..), fill = 
 Accident_Severity_combined)) +  
 scale_fill_manual(values = ("Serious" = "blue","Slight" = "red")) + 
 geom_text(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..)), label = 
 scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat = "count", vjust = -0.25) +
 scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) + 
 labs(title = "Accident Severity by Road Type", y = "Percent", x = "Road Type")
```

Comment: You forgot to put `c()` in `scale_fill_manual(values = c("Serious" = "blue","Slight" = "red"))`

Comment: worked like a charm - have been struggling with this for past hour! 
thx! 

Follow up question --
How would I indicate the proportion of the ''fill variable'' in percentage form within the bar? ie.. if a bar is 80% of my total.. how do I show that 20% of the 80% of accidents were fatal and rest not fatal? 
Another way of saying it -- Given that the bar is color coded, how can I indicate the percentage associated to each segment within the bar?

Comment: `+ geom_text(aes(label = sprintf("%.2f%%", EachTypeCount/Total * 100))` This will show percent on top of bar till 2 decimal places.

Comment: Unfortunately I got the below error -- will post my current graph to demo what I currently have -- Id like the percentages to be more granular at the ''severity level''

Error in +scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) : 
  invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: Ok. Always post glimpse of data alongwith the code and expected output.

Comment: happy to do so -- not sure what the best way to show data here is though -?

Comment: Ouptu something like this https://www.google.co.in/search?biw=1242&bih=588&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=Aq_LWr2sMsqAvQTlnJSgDw&q=bar+chart+with+percent+labels+in+r&oq=bar+chart+with+percent+labels+in+r&gs_l=psy-ab.3...26131.26799.0.26905.5.5.0.0.0.0.203.203.2-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..4.0.0....0.WwjvSZTxfwk#imgrc=61gnz89iFyIV1M:

Comment: more like this but without adding to 100% -- the percentage break down is what I am after

https://www.google.co.in/search?biw=1242&bih=588&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=Aq_LWr2sMsqAvQTlnJSgDw&q=bar+chart+with+percent+labels+in+r&oq=bar+chart+with+percent+labels+in+r&gs_l=psy-ab.3...26131.26799.0.26905.5.5.0.0.0.0.203.203.2-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..4.0.0....0.WwjvSZTxfwk#imgrc=u7-dyUFqMfVX6M: